# ER Diagram Design

Tags: database-design, erd

[image]

I need Help in making ER diagram that i made a ER diagram of each seperate or making it combine I made it seprate as image attached but how to combine and make it one ER diagram.

Module – 1: User Management

Students, parents and teachers will have to register with system to use it. Admin staff member will create account of students, teachers and share account details with them. Parents will be able to register from any location which will be approved by admin.

Module – 2: Class Room Management

Student class information like record of each class and subjects offered in particular class. Students in each class and teacher’s information for particular class will be maintained in this module. Admin staff will able to maintain information of all courses offered, creation of class like which students are in a particular class, courses offered and teachers who will teach the class.

Module- 3: Examination Management

Exams scheduling, date sheet, and results will be manage in this module. Students, teachers and parents will be able to see the report/result card. Teachers will enter student’s marks through this module and admin will manage exams schedule and date sheet.

Module- 4: Time Table Management

Scheduling of class time, exams date sheet and schedule generation, students will be managed in this module. Teacher will be able to maintain the attendance records of students. Admin will be able to maintain attendance record of teachers and parents will be able to see the attendance of their children.

Module 5: Financial Management

All financial activities like student fee and other financial management will be performed by this module.

Module 6: Announcements and News Management

All announcements and news about any activity like start of classes, holidays, exams etc. will be managed through this module.

Answer (score 0):

If you attached the ER Diagrams you made for the other modules it would be easier for us to advise on how to relate them. But you basically should have tables that create a relationship across models, and that's how you would combine them into a final single ER Diagram.

For example, the **Class Room Management** module will likely have it's own table of `Subjects` that has a one to many relationship with it's own table of `Courses` (one subject could have multiple courses, e.g. the Math subject has Calculus 101 course, Calculus 201 course, etc). Then there'll also be a table of `Classes` which has a many-to-one relationship on `Courses` (e.g. Calculus 201 course is currently taught by 3 different teachers, so it has 3 classes it relates to currently). `Classes` will also have a many-to-many relationship on your `Students` table in **Module 1** by storing the `Std_Id` field too, which represents which students are registered to which particular classes. You can follow the same pattern for teachers, etc.

Now your **Module 1** and **Module 2** ER Diagrams are related and linked together. You can follow the same pattern throughout the rest of the modules.

Also, one word of advice for your **Module 1** diagram. It looks like you have a lot of duplicate information because you have defined a separate table for each type of user. You could (and probably should) [**normalize**](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) those into only one or two tables. For example you can have just a single `Users` table that stores the fields `AccountId`, `Password`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `AccountType`. The `AccountType` field would determine if it's an Admin, Teacher, or Student, etc type of account. This refactored design reduces data redundancy and can improve query efficiency.